# The question about the meaning of quasi-geodesic/isometric

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

While watching the [lecture](https://youtu.be/Otpms8PsKrA?t=282) about the Techimüller space, I have tried to study some basic concepts whose lecturer refers. But I don't know the meaning of '[quasi-geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry#Quasigeodesics_and_the_Morse_lemma)' or [quasi-isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry#Definition) which is related to the Hyperbolic space. In Eculicedan Space, I can say roughly someone the meaning of geodesic and isometry: Geodesic is the shortest path on the surface and isometry preserves the length from the surface to another surface.

**But, I want to find out the literal meaning 'quasi-geodesic/isometry...'.** According to the dictionary, 'quasi' means 'seemingly',' apparently but not really'.From googling or the [lecture on the part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Otpms8PsKrA&t=1746s), the path of quasi-geodesic is more bizarrely serpentine than the straight line (on the hyperbolic plane) but I cannot find the clue why such path is called 'quasi-geodesic. And In the case of 'quasi-isometric', similarly, I also want to vindicate why the name of it.

Comment: Are you asking what is the definition of quasigeodesic? And of quasi-isometry? If not, what are you asking?

Comment: Or, if you are asking what the combining form "quasi" means, it would make more sense to use the original Latin meaning, which is "almost".